# Oracle - TO_CLOB doesn't work on SELECT to convert a 4000 CHARs long String

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, clob

I am trying to execute the below SQL in SQL Developer:

```
select to_clob('yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyuuuyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
')  a from dual;
```

And it always gives me `ORA-01704: String literal too long`

Any idea why it doesn't work for me?

I am using Oracle 12.2.0.1.0

Edit: I understand this is possible in a PL/SQL solution. I would like to know if there is a way to do this in SQL.

Comment: Unless you set `MAX_STRING_SIZE = extended` (which I'm not recommending as it's a non-trivial database-wide change that you can't undo) strings in SQL can't be longer than 4000 characters, and the one above is 4003.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson According to this thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3933016?start=15&tstart=0 In post #22, they have successfully used TO_CLOB() to circumvent this limitation. But the subsequent post says it doesn't work for them just as it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why avoid PL / SQL? This is the simplest solution for strings <= 32767 bytes/chars, even easier with version 12c because you can use WITH-FUNCTION clause:

```
with 
  function q return clob is 
  begin
    return q'[1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888888999999999911111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555666666666677777777778888888888899999999991111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888889999999999
]';
  end;
SELECT length(q) FROM dual;

 LENGTH(Q)
----------
     28416
```

---

Longer strings must be divided into pieces shorter than 32,000

```
with 
function q return clob is 
    x clob;
begin
    x := rpad('1',32000,'1');
    x := x || rpad('2',32000,'2');
    x := x || rpad('3',32000,'3');
    x := x || rpad('4',32000,'4');
    x := x || rpad('5',32000,'5');
    x := x || rpad('6',32000,'6');
    x := x || rpad('7',32000,'7');
    return x;
end;
SELECT length( q ) from dual;

 LENGTH(Q)
----------
    224000
```

---

At some point, however, you can exceed the limit of the size of a single SQL command, according to the documentation this limit is unknown:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm#i288032

> **Note:** The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space, and memory

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea why it doesn't work for me?

String literals can't exceed 4000 characters unless you set `MAX_STRING_SIZE = extended`, which is a database-wide change that requires a restart and can't be undone.

> I would like to know if there is a way to do this in SQL.

Convert shorter string literals (<= 4K) to CLOBs and concatenate the results.

```
select to_clob('yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyuuuyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy')
    || to_clob('yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
')  a
from dual;
```

Comment: This was helpful as I am on Oracle 11g, and not 12c, and therefore can't use WITH FUNCTION.